# Collect iterables into one variable (list)

Tags: kotlin

Consider this:

```
  fun readFiles(directory: String): List<File> {
    val result = ArrayList<File>()

    File(directory).walkTopDown().forEach {
      result.addAll(getFiles(it))
    }

    return result
  }

  fun getFiles(file: File): List<File> { ... }
```

How can rewrite this so I don't need to initialize the `result` `ArrayList` but can directly `return File(directory).walkTopDown().???`?

The question is not about what's the best way to read files or anything, just how I can write the above code more concise while doing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` for this purpose. It first maps each element to a `Sequence` using your mapping function (so you kinda get a `Sequence<Sequence<File>>`), then it flattens every result back to a `Sequence<File>`.

Since `walkTopDown` returns a `FileTreeWalk` (which is a subclass of `Sequence<File>`), and you return a `List<File>`, you have to do some conversions as well. You can remove these conversions if you make `getFiles` and `readFiles` return a `Sequence<File>` instead.

```
fun readFiles(directory: String): List<File> {
    return File(directory)
              .walkTopDown()
              .flatMap { getFiles(it).asSequence() }
              .toList()
}
```